# How to add new hindi font kruti dev 010 in CKeditor 4.0.1 font list

Tags: javascript, jquery, css, ckeditor, font-face

I have added

```
config.font_names = 'Kruti Dev 010/KrutiDev10, sans-serif;' +config.font_names;
```

in config.js of CKeditor

And

```
@font-face{ 
font-family: 'krutidev10';
src: url('kruti/kruti_dev_010-webfont.eot');
src: url('kruti/kruti_dev_010-webfont.eot?#iefix') format('embedded-opentype'),
     url('kruti/kruti_dev_010-webfont.woff') format('woff'),
     url('kruti/kruti_dev_010-webfont.ttf') format('truetype'),
     url('kruti/kruti_dev_010-webfont.svg#webfont') format('svg');
```

}

in contents.css of CKeditor

Name is Coming coming in the font list but when i am writing some thing it is typing english words.

Please help me its important

Thanx...

Comment: Are you sure the path is correct? Consider using an absolute path

Comment: Try an absolute path anyway. You're using a relative path, the working directory may be different in the context of the web page.

Comment: can you tell what is absolute path and how to use it?

Comment: The absolute path is the full path to the resource, e.g. `http://www.domain.com/kruti/....` or `/kruti/...` (if the directory is in the domain's root)